# Windows 10 Universal App - ListView Update from Background Thread

Tags: wpf, listview, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have a strange problem here. We develop a Windows 10 Universal App and now I want to update my listview when I add new value. But unfortunately it wont work and I dont really know why. When I add new value it won't update my list view.

The data comes from a background-thread (REST-Request against Server) and therefore I know, I should use something that runs the "add-functionality" on the UI-Thread.

First of all I declared a IProgress and my collection:

```
private List<dtoGemeinde> _listeGemeinden = new List<dtoGemeinde>();


public List<dtoGemeinde> GemeindenCollection
{
            get { return this._listeGemeinden; }
}

IProgress<dtoGemeinde> prog;

prog = new Progress<dtoGemeinde>(UpdateListViewUI);
```

This is the "UpdateListViewUI" method:

```
 public void UpdateListViewUI(dtoGemeinde dto)
 {
           _listeGemeinden.Add(dto);

            this.listViewGemeinden.ItemsSource = GemeindenCollection;
 }
```

And this is the callback method which is called when the background thread, which loads the data from the server, is finished:

```
 public async void onCallBackGemeinden(List<dtoGemeinde> listeGemeinden)
        {
            if (listeGemeinden != null && listeGemeinden.Count > 0)
            {
                this.progress.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;

                foreach (dtoGemeinde dto in listeGemeinden)
                {
                    await listViewGemeinden.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () => prog.Report(dto));              
                }                          
            }
            else
            {
                await new MessageDialog("Data cant be load", "Error").ShowAsync();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you encountering any error messages? What is the nature of it's *"not working"*-ness?

Comment: No there is no error messages. It means, I cant see my listview items.

Comment: Have you tried an ObservableCollection, or implement the INotifyChanged pattern these might help, with the ListView using Databinding to this list

Comment: Thank you RoguePlanetoid! The ObservableCollection was the solution! :)

Comment: Awesome glad I helped, wasn't sure that was answer, will add this to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObservableCollection instead of List usually works fine if need to bind a ListView and be able to see the updates, if this doesn't work any underlying class might need to implement the INotifyChanged pattern to update any properties within the collection if needed.